# Should I store greasy tires separately?

Tags: storage, wheel

Should I store my "greasy" tires separately from the ones that don't seem to sweat?

I'm hand-washing and sorting my bricks from a big, uncovered tub, and some of my earlier tires are really greasy, for lack of a better word... The rubber is, maybe, "sweating" something out with age? I dunno.

I read an earlier post, from 2014 or so, about tire storage, and it was helpful, but not as specific an answer as I was looking for. Any thoughts, yea or nay?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.  https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-lego-rubber-tires/6751#6751 seems like the prior answer you are referring to.

Comment: Truly! Thanks @chicks! That's the post that prompted me to ask for more clarification. I was hoping to catch the eye of an engineer for greater clarification. Here's still hoping!  :D Pleased to be a part of this awesome, resourceful community! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I really expected someone with chemistry leanings to explain to us what was "migrating" out of the rubber with time or temperature, to make them "greasy"...much like cocoa butter will migrate outside of M&M's that have gotten too hot in their package.

The question "chicks" linked to gives some good answers though, and it's encouraging that no one has had any storage tragedies.  Still, I would advise keeping them out of the usual culprits though:  sunlight and hot temperatures.

Comment: Right?! This is all prompted by the discovery of a greasy residue on some childhood bricks left undisturbed for a decade in an attic. No light, but more than a few hot, Midwestern summers... I'm not saying I think it's toxic- I just want to know if I should watch for a certain few years or so, in LEGO tire manufacturing methods, so as to store my collection appropriately... Again, so pleased to have found this resource. *hat-tip*